# IPython on Windows - No highlighting or Auto-complete

Tags: python, windows, django, ipython, django-shell

this has been an issue for a long time for me, but as I mainly develop using Linux I never really cared much about this problem till now.

**iPython on Windows lacks various features.**

**I really miss color <del>highlighting</del> and auto-completion.**

---

**Edit:** fixed highlighting by installing **pyreadline**

> pip install pyreadline

---

Anyone already dealt with this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install [PyReadline](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline),
documentation is [here](http://packages.python.org/pyreadline/introduction.html).

Comment: still no auto-completion though :(

Comment: Tab completion works for me after installing PyReadline. This in a Windows XP machine with Python 2.5. Installed PyReadline 1.7.

Comment: same here, colors and auto-completion appear after installing PyReadline.

Comment: Works on windows  7 64 bit. Colors and auto complete.